# Error: int cannot be converted to boolean

Tags: java

Inside of a for loop is an if statement. Inside that if statement is another for statement, which is throwing me the error - int cannot be converted to boolean. I will include my variables with summaries of them as well.

I have messed around with this already, trying to do different loops and such. I am hoping to be able to at least get rid of the error so I can continue debugging.

Rest of code:

```
private boolean validateCard()
    {
        int odd;
        int even;
        String input = creditCard.getText(); // Get the input from credit card text field.
        tokensList = new ArrayList<String>(); // Create an array list to be able to add more 2 digit numbers as needed.
        if (input.length() < 16)
            cardValidation.setText("Please enter a card number that is 16 digits long");
        digits = input.split(""); // Convert the string to an array of characters.
        oddDigits = new int[8]; // Create an int array to hold input from the credit card numbers.     
        for (odd = 1; odd < digits.length; odd++)
        {
            doubleDigits = Integer.parseInt(digits[odd]);
            doubleDigits *= 2;
            oddDigits[reIndex] = doubleDigits;
            oddArray[reIndex] = String.valueOf(oddDigits[reIndex]); // Populate a string array the values of the odd numbers.
            odd++; // Increment the odd index so it will add the next odd index to the oddDigits variable. 
            reIndex++; // Increment the resuable index.
        }
        reIndex = 0; // Reset the Reusable index.
```

This is the main problem area.

```
for (int i = 0; i < oddDigits.length; i++)
        {   
            if (oddDigits[i] > 10 && oddDigits[i] < 100)
            {
                oddTokens = oddArray[i].split("");
                int oddInteger;
                if (oddTokens.length > 1)
                {
                    int sum = 0;
                    for (int index = 0; oddTokens.length; index++)
                    {
                        sum += Integer.parseInt(oddTokens[index]);
                    }
                    tokensList.add(oddArray[i]);
                }
            }

        }
```

Variables:

```
    public class Payment extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private boolean valid = false;
private ArrayList<String> tokensList;
private SellerInterface si;
private int[] sumTotal;
private int[] intTokens;
private int[] sumTokens;
private String[] oddDoubles;
private String[] digits; // Digits from the credit card number.
private int[] oddDigits;
private int reIndex = 0; // Reusable Index
private int doubleDigits; // integer for double digits of the credit card values
private int[] evenDigits; // integer for the even digits of the credit card number values
private String[] oddArray; // Array of the odd numbers on the credit card.
private String[] evenArray; // Array of the even numbers on the credit card.
private String[] oddTokens; // Will convert each double digit number to a singular number by adding the two digits together (split method).
```

I want it to be able to allow me to loop the for loop and add up the sum of the 2 digits numbers for the credit card (check sum algorithm). I also would appreciate any advice to be able to simply this code too (it has been a bit of a headache at this point).

Error message:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Your condition in the `for` loop is just `oddTokens.length`, which is an int. You need to compare it to something. Probably `index < oddTokens.length`.

Comment: Thanks! I need to get more sleep haha.